# Move files from multiple folders to a single folder without extension

Tags: copy, extract, move

i am a windows user and i need help with something

i have a folder and in it it has multiple folder.and in those multiple folders i have more folders and in those folder i have files without any extension like jpg,txt etc
here is a sample

> D:\test\1\something1\1235486[file]
>
> D:\test\1\something2\1235486[file]
>
> D:\test\2\something1\1235486[file]
>
> D:\test\2\something2\1235486[file]

so now i want to move all those random number files i.e 123456789[these files are without any extension] to **D:\newtest**

so i will have files like

> D:\newtest\123456789
>
> D:\newtest\123456789
>
> D:\newtest\123456789
>
> D:\newtest\123456789

etc. i could have easily done this with search option if it had a extension.but what can i do now?

Answer (score 0):

Finally Found a solution for this problem

First make another folder where you want to transfer file

lets say i have a folder named **ABC** and i want to transfer its files to **XYZ** [only files not folders]

then open Command prompt [cmd]

and enter this

```
for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('dir /b /s /a-d "d:\abc"') do @copy "%a" "d:\xyz
```

Change the folder names and hit enter.it will transfer all the files in it